# How to disable all "home" keys

Tags: 2.2-froyo

I would like to disable all my home keys for a specified event. Lets say my daughter is playing a game, she is 3.5 years old so she does not have very good coordination when it comes to not touching one of those keys accidentally.

Is there a known app that (through whatever means) disables home keys, and through some other means enables them again.

I define home keys as:

Home, Back, Menu, Search

Being on an HTC evo, the home keys are "part of the screen" which is what makes it annoying.

Side note: What tags should I use? No idea what is appropriate for this question.

Comment: I am going to look further into this and resolve it sometime soon. Been sitting here too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with parents giving their phones for children to play with.  See my [answer here for some related information](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/how-can-i-customize-the-actions-associated-with-my-moto-droids-hardware-buttons/1735#1735).

Essentially, it's a security problem. If I take away your right to use the back button (or more importantly, the home button), then you can't quit my app and therefore I have hi-jacked your phone.

Therefore, the only way you are going to get around this is if there some method to do this with a rooted phone.  Or if an application/game supports some sort of "kid lock" that might not be foolproof.  Developers can override the back/menu/search button intents, but I don't think they can override the home button unless it is a home launcher app.

[Take a quick look at this search on the Android market](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=parent+lock).  There are some games specifically tailored to this problem that you might find interesting.

Comment: Security wise, it makes perfect sense, but it makes sense also if asking permissions to hijack the phone (for Good, not Evil). Would be interesting if a Root App existed to do this.

Comment: I guess it would be a nice addition to android if we had an ability to make some sort of lock. Like say press power 4 times to unlock. TBH, this is annoying to even me, when playing a game. The Samsung Galaxy S3's hard button helps a lot if games disable menu or back though.