# How can I use the camera button to pause/resume mp3?

Tags: keyboard, buttons, keyboard-shortcuts, mp3-player

How can I change camera button functionally and use it (or any other physical button) to pause/resume mp3 in a media player app? It is very important for my, because I want be able to pause/resume mp3 without looking to screen of the phone.

Actually my phone (Xperia Mini Pro) has a hardware keyboard with 42 keys, but a few apps use this button as a keyboard shortcut (X-plore is one of few programs that uses hardware keyboard properly).

Comment: See also the answers on [How can I customize the actions associated with my Moto Droid's hardware buttons?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple choices on how to accomplish this:

### Using a headset

If you've got a 1-button-headset connected, you can facilitate that button. There are multiple apps on the playstore providing enhanced possibilities to this -- just [search for "headset-control](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=headset-control&c=apps). Having a Philips headset, I use [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset), which works pretty well; you might have to try several of the available choices to find the one suiting you best.

Most of these apps offer things like:

- configure a media player app to be started as soon as the headset gets connected
- play/pause (or accept an incoming call) with a single press
- skip forward (or reject an incoming call) pressing twice
- increase volume by holding the button, decrease it by one click followed by holding it
- skip backward (triple click)

Actions are usually configurable.

### Without a headset

Re-defining a hardware button can be achieved e.g. using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), which is an automation app for Android (to be more precise: it's the most complete automation app available; costs ~ 5 Euro, a 7-day-trial is available at the homepage, but it's worth every cent). The [Tasker manual states](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html):

> Simulate Media Button: when selected, any media player which listens for Media Button events can be controlled. Without it, the only the Android system media player will respond.
>
> Note: the Toggle Pause function may not work unless playback has already been started manually.

And yes: You can bind that action to...

- Button: Camera
- Button: Long Search

amongst others. You could even bind it to a "shake pattern" (e.g. shake left-right to skip a title).

#### Example:

- *Condition:* Event → Hardware → Button: Camera
- *Task:* Media → Media Control → Cmd: Toggle Pause

Comment: Thanks, Is there also any player with shortcut customization feature like X-plore ?

Comment: I don't know that -- never checked whether a player had shortcuts. All I saw was widgets... But app recommendations are off-topic here (see [FAQ]).

Comment: I installed tasker and I use TTpod as mp3 player, can you please say how can I configure it to pause/resume mp3?

Comment: I never tried especiall that. But in theory: *Condition:* Event->Hardware->Button: Camera; *Task:* Media->Media Control->Cmd: Toggle Pause